# Raster Catalog to Raster Dataset giving ERROR 999999

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, raster-catalog, raster-dataset

I have a problem converting my Raster Catalog to Raster Dataset. I have an error (see below) after 4-5 hours of process - all rasters have ~21Gb.

Is there something wrong with my data?

[image]

[image]

Comment: OK this is a stab in the dark but you have a Geographic Transformation environment setting set (NAD_1927_TO_NAD_1983_NADCON) but no output coordinate setting, I suggest you clear that entry?

Comment: I hope I've solved the problem but still my work is in process. I had 2 rasters out of extent and some of them had broken bands so I didn't load them to Raster Dataset. We'll see what happens - I will let you know about results :)